# What does "live by practice" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "live by practice" mean? It's from *The Invisible Man*

> He turned aside, walked out of the room, and went into his little consulting-room and lit the gas there. It was a little room, because Dr. Kemp did not **live by practice**, and in it were the day's newspapers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that Dr. Kemp did not depend on the fees from his medical practice for his living. Presumably . he had some  investments or land, or some other source of income or money, so the fees his patients paid were not essential to his ability to obtain the necessities and luxuries of life.

I have encountered this expression exclusively in British novels set  (and mostly written) prior to the 1940s, particularly in the works of [R Austin Freeman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._Austin_Freeman), whose writing career stretched from 1904 to 1942, and whose writing was thought a bit old-fashioned when it was first published.  I don't think this phrase is in current use.

Note that *The Invisible Man* contains many idioms and phrases now out-of-date that should not be imitated in current speech or writing.

Comment: It is not in current use because of the National Health Service in Britain. Before that, all general practitioners had to run their practice as a private business.

Comment: @kate That is true, but I believe this expression had become rare before the NHS became widespread, that it was in fact on the decline in the 1930s, and people would find other ways of saying this. Also, the "gentleman-doctor" who lived from private wealth had become far less common. This phrase was never common in the US, to my knowledge, even though there is nothing like the NHS here, even now. Google Ngrams does not find enough uses to plot, for this or for "live from his practice'